# Array element access in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

I was trying to create a Table of Contents in the command line. Each element in the array is a string variable.

```
arr = [chap1, chap1_page, chap2, chap2_page, chap3, chap3_page]
x = 0

until x == arr.length
if ((arr[x] != 0 ))
    puts arr[x].ljust(line/2) + arr[x += 1].rjust(line/2)       
end 
x += 1
end
```

I was wondering if someone could explain the second half of the `puts` statement. I'm not sure why `arr[x+=1]` works but `arr[x+1]` does not. As far as I know, they are the same, are they not?

Comment: Side note: this isn't really idiomatic Ruby. Are you familiar with `Array#each`? As a side effect, you wouldn't need to use a counter variable like this. More on topic: what do you mean by "works" and "does not [work]"? If `x` is 2, then `arr[x + 1]` should return the element at index 3. What output are you seeing that you didn't expect?

Comment: I want the output to format where the chapter is on the left and page is on the right and then repeat on the next line. But with x+1 i am seeing the next line show chap1_page         ....chap2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x + 1` returns that value and has no side effect (does not change the reference of `x`). `x += 1` reassigns `x` and returns that value.

Comment: Thank you, I knew that the += was reassigning x but could not understand why it was giving me the output I wanted. I realize now that I am incrementing x twice, once in the puts statement and a second time at the end of the loop. THAT is why my output is  what I want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with `Enumerable`s like arrays and hashes, it's useful to search the documentation to see if there's something there that will make your code higher level and more expressive.  In this case, you can use `each_cons` to give you the pairs so you don't need to use array indexes at all:

```
2.3.0 :004 > [1,2,3,4].each_cons(2).to_a
 => [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Also, rather than using `if` statements, it's better IMO to use `select` and `reject`.

Also, intermediate local variables can make your code more readable.

Using these ideas, your code could look something like this:

```
array = [chap1, chap1_page, chap2, chap2_page, chap3, chap3_page]

width = line / 2

array.each_cons(2).reject { |x,y| x == 0 }.each do |left, right|
  puts left.ljust(width) + right.ljust(width)
end
```

(I haven't tested this code, but it shows the general idea.)

You could break down those enumerable calls and assign intermediate values to local variables if that makes it clearer for you:

```
array = [chap1, chap1_page, chap2, chap2_page, chap3, chap3_page]
width = line / 2

pairs = array.each_cons(2)
nonzero_pairs = pairs.reject { |x,y| x == 0 }
nonzero_pairs.each do |left, right|
  puts left.ljust(width) + right.rjust(width)
end
```